# Database for small IOT devices

Tags: python, linux, database, iot, low-memory

I am looking for a database for IOT device. It should have below features.
   1. Very low memory usage. (The device will have only 2-4 GB memory for the database).
   2. Data to be stored in the database is not very large.
   3. It should be very fast.
   4. It should support Python.
   5. It can be installed on Linux.
   6. It can be NoSQL or relational.

Could you please suggest some databases for this requirements?

Comment: 2 - 4 *GB* is "very low memory" these days? :)

Comment: Yes. But the device is an old device.

Comment: The question belongs here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I've used SQLite (http://sqlite.org) for projects like this in the past when I wanted a relational front end.

Back in the day I might use BerkeleyDB, or any of its close relatives which offer a simple key-value store, but it is likely no longer buzzword compliant anymore.

Comment: Thanks G.K. McIntire.

Comment: sqlite is the standard choice for embedded devices, smartphones etc. https://www.sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase as it is real-time light weight, NoSQL database and there are various Api's easily available on internet to connect arduino or raspberry pi to the firebase database .

Comment: This should be a comment